# Can anyone tell me from which dask.dataframe wins in memory efficiency than pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

In terms of memory RAM efficiency , who much better?

What dask do to reduce/compress large data to runs on small RAM?

Answer (score 1):

When running on a single machine with datasets smaller than RAM, pandas/numpy should help you run fine. Dask is a distributed task distribution package, which basically means you can lazily read datasets on single computers. For example, a folder of .csvs, that together are too big (60 GB) to load into memory., can be loaded with dask so you **only use the data when you need it**, by calling dask.dataframe.compute().
Basically, start with using pandas - if your code starts throwing MemoryErrors, you can use dask instead.

Source:
http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/why.html

Comment: Then why i try to compute with dask , but my kernel was been forced to shutdown(i try to compute large files more than available memory).
- And if i try to read_csv with dask to a variable , is a variable not in memory?

Comment: Dask divides the data into smaller chunks that are more manageable by your system. That might be an issue, if the chunksize still is too big for your system. As for the your question on read_csv, dask imports the dataframe as a location on disk, so the different attributes (cells) aren't calculated or displayed until explicitly called. Try editing the original question, providing some sample code, that shows what you're trying to do.